# Updating pandas Dictionary Python while looping

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

I am trying to implement the `dash component` - `dropdown` `menu` in `python`:

According to [dash:](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components)

my `option` parameter needs to follow this pattern:

```
options=[
    {'label': 'New York City', 'value': 'NYC'},
    {'label': 'Montréal', 'value': 'MTL'},
    {'label': 'San Francisco', 'value': 'SF'}
],
value='MTL')
```

I am interested in using a `column` with company names in my `pandas dataframe` as the `dropdown`

So I realised that I could leverage on the `python dictionaries`:

```
mydict = {}
option = []

for comp in df.company:
    mydict["label"] = comp 
    mydict["value"] = comp 
    option.append(mydict)
```

`printing` `option` results into the what I expect but with only the first `company` in the company name column. It repeated this all through. What is wrong with my operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the problem that python lists only store [references](https://www.quora.com/Does-Python-list-store-pointers-to-the-actual-array-items). As you only have one dictionary all elements (references) in your list will point to the same dictionary. You have to create a new dictionary for each option:

```
option = []

for comp in df.company:
    mydict = {}
    mydict["label"] = comp 
    mydict["value"] = comp 
    option.append(mydict)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a one-liner for this:

```
options = [{"label":x, "value":x} for x in df.company]
```